# Create session variables on a event at login button

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I'm getting `NullReferenceException` when I'm trying to create `Session` variables that is using `Membership.GetUser()` on `LoginUser_LoggedIn` event. The login page is created automatically. The problem is that `Membership.GetUser().UserName` is returning `null`. I don't know why because if I remove this code and login normally I won't get `null` from this, only when I use this event.

So, I want to be able to get the username of the logged in user so I can create these session variables on the `LoggedIn` event

```
protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["PersonPID"] = con.GetPerson(Membership.GetUser().UserName.ToString()).PID;
        Session["PersonFirstName"] = con.GetPerson(Membership.GetUser().UserName).FirstName;
        Session["PersonLastName"] = con.GetPerson(Membership.GetUser().UserName).LastName;
        Session["PersonDob"] = con.GetPerson(Membership.GetUser().UserName).Dob;
        Session["PersonTown"] = con.GetPerson(Membership.GetUser().UserName).Town;
        Session["PersonGender"] = con.GetPerson(Membership.GetUser().UserName).Gender;
        Session["PersonUname"] = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
        Session["PersonImageUrl"] = con.GetPerson(Membership.GetUser().UserName).ImageUrl;
        Session["PersonPres"] = con.GetPerson(Membership.GetUser().UserName).Pres;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `User.Identity.Name` (as `Page` has a `User` property)?

Comment: Efficiency remark: you can call that `Membership.GetUser().UserName` once and store&reuse that result. The same for `con.GetPerson()`.

Answer (score 0):

Get it from the textbox used to login
string userName = (LoginUser.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox).Text;

The issue here appears to be that the user is not yet authenticated fully (it's value is not yet showing in the membership classes). 
Also the profile of the user has not been loaded so we cannot get profile date either.

Kind of makes the event a little pointless in my opinion.

NOTE: we have to get the username value from the text box in the form but this is hidden by it's parent control, hence parentControl.FindControl(textbox)

You could also do this is you want to be really generic

Control ctrl = ((System.Web.UI.Control)sender);
String userName = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)ctrl.FindControl("UserName")).Text;

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest, first you validate the User credentials in `LoginUser_Authenticate()` method which will redirect you to `LoginUser_LoggedIn()` method after successful login. There you can get the current user name and set to your Session variables.

```
protected void LoginUser_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (Login1.UserName == "SomeUser1" && Login1.Password == "password123")
    {
        e.Authenticated = true;
    }

    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }
}

protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["PersonPID"] = con.GetPerson(Login1.UserName).PID;
    Session["PersonFirstName"] = con.GetPerson(Login1.UserName).FirstName;
    Session["PersonLastName"] = con.GetPerson(Login1.UserName).LastName;
    Session["PersonDob"] = con.GetPerson(Login1.UserName).Dob;
    Session["PersonTown"] = con.GetPerson(Login1.UserName).Town;
    Session["PersonGender"] = con.GetPerson(Login1.UserName).Gender;
    Session["PersonUname"] = Login1.UserName;
    Session["PersonImageUrl"] = con.GetPerson(Login1.UserName).ImageUrl;
    Session["PersonPres"] = con.GetPerson(Login1.UserName).Pres;
}
```